# vmware screen is too small for install

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, centos-7

I am using vmware 9.0.4 and I have a strange problem.

I am trying to install CentOS7.1 as a guest OS. When I come to the screen manual partitioning the lower part of the screen is unavailable because the screen is too small - it doesn't fit in the screen provided by vmware host.

So I am unable to set up partitioning because I can not access the lower part of the screen. I have tried setting display to auto detect and display maximum resolution of any one monitor - 2560 x 1600 no luck

Question. 
How can I increase the screen size available to me so I can access the lower part of the partitioning screen?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably "VMware *Workstation* 9.0.4"? You've tagged this "vmware-workstation" and "vmware-player". Which is it?  What is your host OS?

Comment: Ratagged to workstation